# IE7 Classic ASP Cache

Tags: asp-classic, session-variables

I have a classic asp website that uses Session variables to store login state ie. userid, isloggedin, etc. On logout, the session variables are reset and Session.Abandon() is called followed by a redirect to the login page. In IE7 I have noticed that after logout I can type in a previously visited url and see what appears to be a cached version of its state prior to the logout. Hitting ctl-f5 will reload from the server again and redirect to the login page. This is the behavior I want to occur even if the url is type in without the ctl-f5. Does anyone know how to get this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set the no-cache headers  so that the pages do not get cached in the first place. see:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067

Answer (score 2):

I think mkoryak's answer (using no-cache headers) seems best.  If you want certain pages to be seen only when a user is logged in,  the best way is to instruct the browser to simply not cache the page.  Furthermore,  schemes such as tweaking cookies and using javascript do determine login state on the client are simply reinventing the wheel.

If you want to leverage some caching and your page isn't something that is constantly updating, a good compromise is to set the `Response.Expires` header to some value you deem appropriate (it's measured in minutes I believe).

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem before, but whenever I've clicked a link on that page, it's asked me to log back in.

You could try either resetting sessionID = "" or sessionID = "XYZ" and make XYZ something your code ignores on log out.

You could also try setting no-cache headers.

Answer (score 0):

You could send no-cache however thats quiet a performance hit just to get what you want. I prefer Liams suggestion and ensuring that everything you do from that page requires you to be logged in, that way no one can do anything they shouldn't. What if its a email system though or similar, the people "could" view other peoples emails which are cached, in those instances then yes, not caching sensitive information is the way to go (you can't cache HTTPS pages by default for instance).

You could also include some javascript in the head which could check for the existance of a "logged in" cookie. This would run every time they loaded the page, if no cookie exists then JS could redirect you off to the login page. Not 100% fool proof but good enough. You logout page would need to clear this cookie and you login page set it.